# Next term of the series

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

Find the next term of the series $79,95,25,39,99,$____

$(1)$ $117$

$(2)$ $81$

$(3)$ $243$

<sup>Source: IBPS PO mains exam in India</sup>

Comment: Don't forget to reference where this came from

Comment: Actually this came in IBPS PO mains exam in India.

Comment: @mathmaniac. Which book did you use to get a source of all the passt year questions of SBI PO and IBPS PO?

Comment: @Rajarshi Koyal sorry for the very late reply. I was doing all these questions just for fun from gradeup in the semester break just for fun. Actually I am in academics and I am willing to do research at some day. Now I am pursuing Masters from ISI.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer could be

> $81$

Reasoning

> For a 2-digit number $N$, let $S(N)$ be the sum of its digits and let $T(N)$ be the result of subtracting the first digit from the second digit.
>  The formula for the $n$th term of the sequence $a_n$ is given recursively by
>  $$ a_n = a_{n-1} + \left[S\left(a_{n-1}\right) \times \left(T\left(a_{n-1}\right) - 1\right)\right]$$

Examples

> $79 \rightarrow 79 + \left[(7+9) \times (9-7-1)\right] = 79 + 16 = 95$
>  $95 \rightarrow 95 + \left[(9+5) \times (5-9-1)\right] = 95 - 70 = 25$
>  $25 \rightarrow 25 + \left[(2+5) \times (5-2-1)\right] = 25 + 14 = 39$
>  $39 \rightarrow 39 + \left[(3+9) \times (9-3-1)\right] = 39 + 60 = 99$
>  $99 \rightarrow 99 + \left[(9+9) \times (9-9-1)\right] = 99 - 18 = 81$